# Java regex string matching (like and not like)

Tags: java, regex, string

Lets say I have 3 strings

```
String string1 = "THE SUM OF TWO"
String string2 = "HOT SUMMER"
String string3 = "SUM IN SUMMER"
```

Now, I search for strings which have "SUM" and not "SUMMER".

```
String patt = ".*?SUM.*?"
String notpatt = ".*?SUMMER.*?"
Pattern regex = Pattern.complie(patt)
Pattern nonregex = Pattern.complie(notpatt)
```

looping through each string here

```
if(regex.matcher(string1).matches()){
    if(nonregex.matcher(string1).matches()){
        System.out.println(false);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(true);
    }
}
```

Now, I need to get true for string3, where it has 'SUM' in it. But, as it also have 'SUMMER' it's giving me false.

Is there any library that I can use? or 
Is there any other way to get my expected result?

Thanks,
Prithvi.

Comment: If you are searching for sum use the pattern "\\<SUM\\>".

Comment: Seems it's enough just to check for pattern 'SUM not followed by M', so there's should be only single `Pattern/Matcher` and call to `find()` (not `matches()`, as this checks if _entire_ string is matched by pattern).

Comment: @vks is correct you can use like \bSUM\b

Answer (score 1):

Since `matches` tries to match the pattern against the whole string (checks that the whole string is matched by the given pattern), you need to add `.*` at the first and the last in your pattern. Word boundary `\b` will do this job but it also matches the string `SUM` in the input  `FOO:SUM:BAR`

```
String patt = ".*?(?<=\\s|^)SUM(?=\\s|$).*";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(patt);
String[] test = {"THE SUM OF TWO", "HOT SUMMER", "SUM IN SUMMER"};
for (String s: test) {
    if(regex.matcher(s).matches()){
        System.out.println(true);
    } else {
        System.out.println(false);
    }
```

**Output:**

```
true
false
true
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\\s|^)` Asserts that the string `SUM` must be preceded by a space or start of the line anchor `^`.
- `SUM(?=\\s|$)` Asserts that the string `SUM` must be followed by a space or end of the line anchor `$`.

Comment: Yes, this will work. But, what if the string is like "THESUMS ARE WRONG THIS SUMMER" this should come out as true. As it has 'SUM' in string other than in 'SUMMER'?

Comment: i think want to get true only for the strings which has `SUM` as complete word. `THESUMS`, in this the word SUM is preceeded by `THE` and followed by `S`, it isn't a complete word. May i know what are your requirements?

Comment: Did you don't want the string `SUM` only if it's followed by `MER`? If yes, then try this `SUM(?!MER)` regex.

Comment: No, not as complete word. That pattern(SUM) could be any where in string but not in specified pattern `notpatt="SUMMER"`

Comment: @Y.Prithvi did you try this regex `.*SUM(?!MER).*` ?

Comment: I appreciate this. But, can it be more dynamic? We can do this if only for `SUMMER`, what if I have a list and I have to check each one?

Comment: just add it to the negated character class like `.*SUM(?!MER|BLAH|FOO).*`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I tried

```
    String patt = ".*?SUM\\s+.*?";
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(patt);
    String[] test = {"THE SUM OF TWO", "HOT SUMMER", "SUM IN SUMMER"};
    for (String s: test) {
        if(regex.matcher(s).matches()){
            System.out.println(true);
        } else {
            System.out.println(false);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
true
false
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expected result is nothing but to check whether the `String` contains the `SUM` word(already suggested by user ***Victor Sorokin***). For that you can simply use word boundaries. I just simplified your code a bit.

```
String[] strings = {"THE SUM OF TWO","HOT SUMMER","SUM IN SUMMER"};
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(".*\\bSUM\\b.*");

for(String string : strings){
    System.out.println(pat.matcher(string).matches());
}
```

But to be frank your code is working as fine for the requirement *'I search for strings which have "SUM" and not "SUMMER"'*. Think once.

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*?\bSUM\b.*$
```

Use this.`\b` will make sure it matches `SUM` and not `SUMMER`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/vR4fY4/5